# IPTables : prevent UDP Flooding

Tags: iptables, ddos

I want to stop the UDP flooding on the Linux device.

I have written a simple IPTable rule to drop all UDP packets

iptables -A INPUT -p udp DROP

But still the DoS attack happens and the device gets hanged. Any clue on how to prevent a UDP flooding?

Every Answer is appreciated.

Comment: Your upstream provider. iptables is still handling the traffic and if it can't cope it'll still hang.

Comment: Still the same rate of TCP packet flooding is managed effectively by the same device. Why not UDP?

Comment: UDP floods tend to be much larger because there's no handshake overhead involved. You can *easily* have these floods stopped at an upstream router that just filters UDP. Are you sure it's just not saturating your bandwidth? If it is, not much you can do anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block the traffic at an upstream router. You can't make those packets magically disappear, so if your device is so underpowered that it can't handle dropping UDP packets, you'll need to do that with another device.

Comment: Its expected the device to be of standalone and still manage a UDP flooding? Is it possible some way?

Comment: You described how do to it in your original question.

Comment: Also the TCP flooding is managed by it effectively, in UDP flooding alone it fails? What can be the difference?

Comment: You would use `-p tcp` for TCP and `-p udp` for UDP. But it's the same rule.

Comment: Yes i'm using the rule -p udp , But with lower rate of UDP flooding is managed effectively now with the same rule. Still the question is - the UDP flooding at the same rate as TCP flooding is faster than TCP?

Comment: "Yes", but I wouldn't call it faster. But you can pass more traffic with less overhead.